# How to get multiple value in one variable with ' '

Tags: mysql, sql

How i can get value like this in a variable 'TFSEP-2019','TFjul-2018','TFJun-2018'  without spaces.

```
SELECT s.house, s.grade, s.homeroom AS Campus
FROM student s,fees_jrl f
WHERE s.studnum = f.studnum AND
      f.name IN (' TFJun-2018 TFJul-2018 ') AND
      f.trans_type= 'chg' AND
      f.paid_id is NULL AND s.house LIKE '%'
GROUP BY s.house
```

I am getting like this ('TFJun-2018 TFJUL-2018 TFSEP-2019')  but I want like ('TFSEP-2019','TFjul-2018','TFJun-2018') please help

Comment: Your question has no code or variable.  It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: `s.house LIKE '%'` is the same as `s.house is not null`.

Comment: It would help if you showed sample data and expected output.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: its not s.house its paid_id is NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may refer the following statements with like operators, whenever you need quotes(`'`), use doubled-quotes(`''`) :

```
create table tab ( Id int, expression varchar(100));

insert into tab values(1 ,'TFJun-2018 TFJUL-2018 TFSEP-2019');
insert into tab values(2,'''TFJun-2018'',''TFJUL-2018'',''TFSEP-2019''');

select * from tab where expression like '''TFJun-2018''%';
Id  expression
2   'TFJun-2018','TFJUL-2018','TFSEP-2019'
```

*or*

```
select * from tab where expression like '''TFJun-2018'',''TFJUL-2018''%';
Id  expression
2   'TFJun-2018','TFJUL-2018','TFSEP-2019'
```

*or*

```
select * from tab where expression like '''TFJun-2018'',''TFJUL-2018'',''TFSEP-2019''%'; 
Id  expression
2   'TFJun-2018','TFJUL-2018','TFSEP-2019'
```

[***Rextester Demo***](http://rextester.com/AAHI5001)

Answer (score 0):

use explicit join and concat

```
    SELECT  
 concat( concat( concat( concat("'",s.house),"'"),concat( concat("'",s.grade),"'")),
  concat( concat("'",s.homeroom),"'"))
    FROM student s join fees_jrl f
    on  s.studnum = f.studnum 
      where f.name IN (' TFJun-2018 TFJul-2018 ') AND
          f.trans_type= 'chg' AND
          f.paid_id is NULL AND s.house LIKE '%'
```

I think you dont need group by as you have no aggregation function

Comment: i want 'TFJUN-2018','TFJUL-2018'  like this

Comment: @MuhammadSaad eidited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use like for strings
% means any chars, _ means one char
So doing 
F.name like %2018% 
Will give you all of 2018..